# Galvanized nails for ACQ treated lumber = must be hot dipped, or not?

Tags: framing, fastener, nails, pressure-treated

We're having some construction done requiring treated soleplates on concrete slab.

As such, galvanized nails were used. However, they don't appear to be hot-dipped. My understanding (going back several years when I was building a deck back when ACQ was relatively new) is that hot dipped is a requirement for ACQ treated lumber.

So I went to get some, but then noticed that a lot of the galvanized nails at Home Depot now say "for all treated wood" even though they clearly aren't hot dipped. [Here's an example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Grip-Rite-3-in-x-0-120-Plastic-Exterior-Galvanized-Ring-Shank-Nails-1-000-per-Box-GR408HG1M/202275376).

Has technology changed a bit and are there now galvanizing methods that are suitable for ACQ that aren't hot dipped? Or is this some shoddy product claims?

I obviously don't want to re-nail every stud to the sole place if it's necessary, but at the same time, I want to make sure the hardware is suitable for ACQ use.

Comment: why don't read the Q&A on the webpage that you linked?

Comment: @jsotola I did. Seems I'm not the only one confused. There's a claim they are hot dipped, another that they are just hot galvanized...which is supposedly different? Hence me asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are different levels of zinc galvanization. If you want it to last longer, then get a thicker layer of zinc on the outside of the steel.

One way to get a thicker layer is to hot dip galvanize it. Another way is use a Simpson hanger that is Z-max plated which is basically just twice electrogalvanized steel plate and actually not hot dipped.

If it's galvanized just a little bit, it'll technically be okay for treated lumber. If you want it to last longer, then get more galvanization on there. Zinc is a sacrificial coating, so as it corrodes it protects the steel less and the steel will begin to rust.

Yes, I would definitely be worried about non-specific product information. If it just says it's galvanized, then assume it's the least amount possible. They'll brag about anything better than the minimum basic electroplating. Look up [Simpson's Corrosion Resistance Recommendations and Classifications](https://www.strongtie.com/solutions/corrosion) to determine your environmental situation and its requirements.

Comment: I'm less concerned about rust (this is all indoor use...or at least inside the weathering envelope) and really just concerned about ACQ. I always thought 'hot dipped' was an absolutely requirement for ACQ, but it seems there are many more galvanizing options out there and some manufacturers claim they are OK with ACQ, but it's fuzzy.

Comment: @DA01 Oh in that case, regular basic electrogalvanized nails used in dry conditions in ACQ lumber is perfect. If it was moist or wet conditions then you'd want hot dipped. That is unless you're within 50 miles or so from a coast and have salty air, but yeah you're fine.

Comment: Do you have any source for that information? I can't find anything conclusive anywhere other than hot-dipped is for ACQ. In my case though, it may be moot as the house is about 500 ft from salt water, so I might just best stick with hot dipped anyways.

Comment: My reading online research is that in dry conditions that rusting is nearly zero even with ACQ wood. Moisture is needed for significant rusting. Contact with concrete could cause some moisture depending on location indoors.